# Можно ли использовать геокодирование в react-yandex-maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api, redux, yandex-maps-jsapi

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла трудность с поиском нормальной документации по react-yandex-maps. Я не могу понять как решить следующую задачу с помощью данной библиотеки, а именно, необходимо принимать адрес вида  (Санкт-Петербург, ул Чудновского, дом 8, к 2) с redux и по нему выставлять метку на карте. Адреса будут динамически обновляться, хотелось бы также избежать постоянного ререндеринга компонента. Вопрос в следующем: можно ли с помощью данной библиотеки получать геопозицию по адресу или производить выставление метки по адресу приведенного формата и если да, то как? Заранее спасибо за помощь и прошу прощения, если спрашиваю очевидные вещи)

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, ссылку на модуль, о котором идет речь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить ссылку на `ymaps` с помощью [`onApiAvaliable`](https://github.com/gribnoysup/react-yandex-maps/blob/master/src/YMaps.js#L11). Эта возможность недокументированная, но, похоже, это единственный способ.

```js
const App = () => (
  <YMaps onApiAvaliable={(ymaps) => console.log(ymaps)}>
    <Map state={mapState}>
    </Map>
  </YMaps>
);
```

Достав `ymaps` вы можете спокойно использовать обычный [`ymaps.geocode`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/).

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { coordinates: null };

  geocode(ymaps) {
    ymaps.geocode('Мытищи')
      .then(result => this.setState({ coordinates: result.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates() }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <YMaps onApiAvaliable={ymaps => this.geocode(ymaps)}>
        <Map state={mapState}>

          { !this.state.coordinates ? null :
            <Placemark geometry={{ coordinates: this.state.coordinates}} />
          }

        </Map>
      </YMaps>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Выглядит похожим на правду, спасибо за ответ, постараюсь в ближайшее время попробовать и сообщу о результатах)

Comment: [корректировка](https://github.com/gribnoysup/react-yandex-maps/blob/4ed36fe4a8b131826608901bd5db0054e12f8458/docs/pages/migration-guide.mdx#L111)

Comment: И по всей видимости данное решение с onLoad не работает

Comment: Разобрался, работает, если добавить подключение модуля в <Map modules={['geocode']}.

Answer (score 3):

На данный момент свойство onApiAvaliable у компонента YMaps не поддерживается, вместо него необходимо использовать свойство onLoad у компонента